# java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: maprfs

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, hadoop, mapreduce, mapr

I am trying to execute/run a web app(using Spring tool suite), through which one can submit jobs to hadoop. i am using **apache-tomcat-6.0.36 server** and **mapr client** for the same. However, when i run my app, i get the following errors:

```
java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: maprfs
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1534)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:69)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:1571)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1553)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:232)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:115)
at com.aexp.lookalike.PreInitialize.createVarFiles(PreInitialize.java:50)
at com.aexp.lookalike.PreInitialize.run(PreInitialize.java:98)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.ToolExecutor.invokeTargetObject(ToolExecutor.java:31)
at org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.ToolExecutor.invokeTargetObject(ToolExecutor.java:27)
at org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.HadoopCodeExecutor.invokeTarget(HadoopCodeExecutor.java:185)
at org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.HadoopCodeExecutor.runCode(HadoopCodeExecutor.java:102)
at org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.ToolTasklet.execute(ToolTasklet.java:33)
at org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.ToolTasklet$$FastClassByCGLIB$$317c6986.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
at org.springframework.data.hadoop.mapreduce.ToolTasklet$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4b232693.execute(<generated>)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:386)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:264)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:250)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Have i missed something while configuring? what can be the cause of this error? have i missed out adding any of the jars to the classpath of the app?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because your classpath does not have the mapr jars. Make sure CLASSPATH and LIBRARY_PATH settings are correct

CLASSPATH should contain the $MAPR_HOME/lib/maprfs-1.0.3-mapr-3.0.0.jar"
LIB_PATH should contain /opt/mapr/lib

Answer (score 0):

I got similar exception but "hdfs". I found the issue to be in application jar that I created using maven with dependencies did not have "services" specs for hdfs that comes with hadoop hdfs jar. I solved it using maven shade plugin (maven-shade-plugin) using its built in transformer "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer".

I think maven without shade plugin would not put hdfs services specs for "org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem" which is required by hdfs FileSystem. My guess is "maprfs" is another filesystem that needs to be specified in the METAINF/services folder. Try providing it manually. You can get it from hadoop hdfs jar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please share your POM example?